# Getting Apache to allow access to Express API over HTTPS

Tags: apache, express, ssl, proxy, port

My website (https://www.tjbrackett.com/contact), which is on Apache, cannot access my Express app that is on the same server over HTTPS. Before I added an SSL certificate to the site, the setup ran perfectly. When I revert the SSL cert, it works again. The error I'm receiving on the front-end is ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

I've tried setting up a proxy/reverse proxy. I'm not sure if I set them up correctly. I've done a self-signed SSL cert on the Express app. I've tried to serve the Express app on top of the HTTPS domain.

HTTPS Apache mysite.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.tjbrackett.com
        ServerAdmin tj@brackett.dev
        ServerAlias tjbrackett.com
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/tjbrackett.com

        <Directory /var/www/tjbrackett.com>
                    order allow,deny
                    allow from all

                    RewriteEngine on

                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
                    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
                    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]

        </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.tjbrackett.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.tjbrackett.com/privkey.pem

ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass /contact https://www.tjbrackett.com:8443/
ProxyPassReverse /contact https://www.tjbrackett.com:8443/

</VirtualHost>
```

Express app

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const app = express();

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert.pem')
}
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let name = req.body.name;
    let email = req.body.email;
    let subject = req.body.subject;
    let message = req.body.message;
    let mailOptions = "";
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.hostname);

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: 'myEmail@bot.com',
            pass: 'jsfoffamlhqzfqnu'
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });
    if (req.hostname === "www.tjbrackett.com"){
        mailOptions = {
            from: email,
            to: 'myEmail@gmail.com',
            subject: subject,
            text: message + "\nName: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email,
        };
    } else {
        mailOptions = {
            from: email,
            to: 'anotherEmail@gmail.com',
            subject: subject,
            text: message + "\nName: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email,
        }
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });

    res.send(req.body);
})

http.createServer(app).listen(8888, () => {
    console.log("Server started on port 8888");
});
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8443, () => {
    console.log("Server started on port 8443");
});
```

React Fetch

```
fetch("https://www.tjbrackett.com:8443", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    name: this.state.name,
    email: this.state.email,
    message: this.state.message
})
```

I've very new to Apache/web servers so at this point I just don't know enough to research the problem. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID means that the certificate is refused because of which CA signed it. So the client does not like that CA. And "I've done a self-signed SSL cert " , yes self-signed certificate are exactly in that case. Either you need to specifically add it in the trust store of your client, or stop using self signed certificate and use one provided by a well known CA (integrated by default in trust stores)

Comment: Would it be possible to link the cert I have for my website to the Express app? I tried setting up a non-self-signed cert for Express but it wasn't allowed to have a custom port number and Apache is taking the 80/443 ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same SSL certificate that's associated with my URL allowed my website to access the Express API.

New Express code

```
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert/info/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert/info/cert.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert/info/chain.pem')
}
```

I used Let's Encrypt/Certbot for the SSL.